# Login with pre-existing database in Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I try to set up a form process in my newest Symfony application. I followed the Symfony's cookbook but with no success.

I want to use a pre existing database where fields loginUtil and passUtil couple are my connection requirements.

So I set my security.yml file like :

```
security:
    providers:
        main:
            entity: Customer\CustomerBundle\Entity\utilisateur
            property: loginUtil
    encoders:
        Customer\CustomerBundle\Entity\utilisateur:
        algorithm: sha1

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: true
            provider: main
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: home_page
```

Set my entity who implements interface UserInterface according documentation

```
<?php
namespace Customer\CustomerdBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * utilisateur
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="utilisateur")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Customer\CustomerdBundle\Repository\utilisateurRepository")
 */

class utilisateur implements UserInterface
{
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $salt;
    private $roles;

    // declaration of other fields from pre existing database

    // setters and getters
    // ...
    //

    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        $this->password = $this->getPassUtil();
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getsalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    public function getusername()
    {
        return $this->username = $this->getLoginUtil();
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
    }
}
?>
```

My controller who only returns my form view :

```
<?php

namespace Customer\CustomerdBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('CustomerCustomerBundle:Default:tableLum.html.twig');
    }

    public function loginAction()
    {
        return $this->render('CustomerCustomerBundle:Default:formLogin.html.twig');
    }
}
```

My routing.yml

```
homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: CustomerCustomerBundle:Default:index }

login:
    path: /login
    defaults:
    _controller: CustomerCustomerBundle:Default:login

login_check:
    path: /login_check

logout:
    path: /logout
```

And my authenticate form :

```
{% extends "CustomerCustomerBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block maincontentFormLogin %}
    <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Login :</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="" />
        <br />
        <label for="password">Mot de passe :</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Connexion" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I saw in `/var/logs/dev.log` that my username is submited correctly and requestes with doctrine but not password, he is empty. So logically my credentials are bad.

Anyone could put me on the way with what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What does your login_check controller look like?

Comment: @Brent Sorry, Question updated thx

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution.

I don't understand why for now. I needed to add somme params inside encoders section like that :

```
encoders:
    Customer\CustomerBundle\Entity\utilisateur:
        algorithm: sha1
        encode_as_base64: false
        iterations: 1
```

I need to document myself now to understand why.

Thx to you guys !!

Comment: By default, most of the password encoders actually loop around and encode the password hundreds or even thousands of times to ensure a more secure hash.  Your existing database only used one.